# What is $\langle (2 1),(3 2),(5 4)\rangle?$

Tags: group-theory

I just want to make sure I am doing this correctly.

> Is $$\langle (2 1),(3 2),(5 4)\rangle=\{(1),(2 1), (3 2), (5 4), (1 2 3), (3 2)(4 5), (2 1)(5 4), (1 2 3)(54)\}?$$

Comment: You can check it yourself using [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/). It's free!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that  a group of order $8$ cannot contain an element of order $3$.

Also notice that elements (21), (32) generate a group $H$ of order 6, (isomorphic to) the symmetric group $\mathfrak S_3$  of 3 elements.
Thus the group has $6n$ elements for some positive $n$.

We con go even further and notice that the group $G$ we are looking for contains the set 
$
H\cdot \langle (54)\rangle
$
It is not hard to check that this is a group of order $12$.

Thus $G$ has at least $12$ elements. Since $H\cdot \langle (54)\rangle$ contains the generators $(21), (32), (54)$ we are done.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Is $(123)^{-1}\in\langle (2 1),(3 2),(5 4)\rangle?$

Comment: $(123)^-1$ is (132), so I don't think it is in the subgroup?

Comment: But if $(123)$ is in a group, what does that tell you about its inverse, @user520403?

Comment: ohhhh right so the inverse must also be in the group, so  that means I've messed up somewhere

Comment: Precisely, @user520403 $\ddot\smile$

Comment: is there a formula or somewhere i can find out how to properly calculate  problem like this

Comment: or is the answer the same I just need to add the inverses i missed : {$(1),(21),(32),(54),(123),(32)(45),(21)(54),(123)(54), (132), (132)(54)$}

Comment: A broad area of study for this sort of thing is combinatorial group theory. Given a set of generators and relations between those generators, one has a *presentation* for a group. Algorithms to decide certain properties of groups given presentations might not even exist (in the sense that there is no Turing machine that, with the presentations as coded input, will halt in finite time with an answer one way or the other). So, in general, no; however: there's GAP. It can churn out an answer for most garden variety groups. Have a look at the link I provided in the comment above, @user520403.